# Convert tabular pandas DataFrame into nested pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, object, nested, tabular

Supposing that i have a simple pd.DataFrame like so:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 20], 'col2': [3, 40], 'col3': [5, 50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df
   col1  col2  col4
0     1     3     5
1    20    40    60
```

is there a way to convert this to nasted pandas Dataframe (df_new) , so as when i call `df_new.values[0]` taking as ouptut:

```
array(
[0    1
 1    3
 2    5
Length: 3, dtype: int], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What exactly is this [0 1 1 3] array?

Comment: So, thanks for the feedback ! 0 and 1 are indexes and and 1 and 3 are values of first row ! Im gonna update my question right now ! Thanks

Comment: Hm... So you want to return value `3` for index `1`?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to convert this dataframe into another, in which when i call this command (df_new.values[0]) taking this as output!

Comment: So what will be the expected array for 2nd row (0 20, 1 40, 2 60)?

Comment: Exactly! But in the above form (as object)!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think I understand the exact requirement, but here is something:

One way of getting the desired `output` is this:

```
>>> pd.Series(df.T[0].values)

0    1
1    3
2    5
dtype: int64
```

If you want to have these as 2d arrays:

```
>>> np.array(pd.DataFrame(df.T[0].values).reset_index())

array([[0, 1],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 5]])

>>> np.array(pd.DataFrame(df.T[1].values).reset_index())

array([[ 0, 20],
       [ 1, 40],
       [ 2, 50]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but the output is not in the proper form . i don't know excactly what type is "df_new.values[0]" but i think it is something like pd.Series !

Comment: how did you get that `object`? Can you please elaborate exactly what is what you're trying to achieve with this..I mean, once you have that data - what do you do with this? Also, what command did you use to extract your `object`?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try to explain you better this time. So in this link: https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime/blob/main/examples/02_classification_univariate.ipynb, in cell [3], the dataframe is read in a "strange" form as you see. Then in Cell [6] is converted to another form. My question is, assuming that we have a dataframe (as in Cell[6]) how we convert this to dataframe form (as in Cell[3])?